# Search a File for Today's Date in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, search

UPDATE:  If you are attempting to search a file for today's date in Python, I have posted my final code in the answers section below.

I have a folder containing logs created by a program.  The log title contains the user's name and the date the log was created.  I am trying to write a Python script that open's logs containing today's date and reads them.  I used *datetime* to get today's date and *if today in logFolderContent[x]* to search for the date.  I was able to get a smaller version of this script working (searching three strings) but when I tried to rewrite it to search the folder I had issues.

Below is my script.  Thanks to the help of @Steven Summers, my code is a bit more neat.  I replaced the old code with the new one.  I've since realized that the script crashes when it tries to interact with today's files.

```
import os
import datetime

#  <><><><><><><><><><><><><><>     Get Today's Date    <><><><><><><><><><>    
today = datetime.date.today()
today = str(today)
runDate = today
print("Today's Date:", today, "\n\n\n")

#  <><><><><><><><><><><><><>     Get all today's files   <><><><><><><><><>    
logFolder = r"\\foamfile\logs\POHistory"
logFolderContent = os.listdir(logFolder)  # WORKING
logFolderContent.reverse()
print("log folder content", logFolderContent)
countFolderContent = len(logFolderContent)  # WORKING
print("Total Files in Folder:", countFolderContent)
eligibleLogs = []
continueLogSearch = "true"
x = 0
for i, file in enumerate(logFolderContent):
    if file.startswith(today):
        eligibleLogs.append(i)
        print("eligibleLogs[i] = ", eligibleLogs[i])
    elif not file.endswith(".txt"):
        print("Non-text file found and ignored")
    print(logFolderContent[i])
```

Here is the output:

```
Today's Date: 2016-07-18

log folder content ['Thumbs.db', '2016-07-18-WIN7-BUYING.txt', (etc...) '2016-04-20-ERIC-NEW.txt']
Non-text file found and ignored
Thumbs.db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:/JustinG/Python/Directory/Complete_1.py", line 24, in <module>
    print("eligibleLogs[i] = ", eligibleLogs[i])
IndexError: list index out of range

process finished with exit code 1
```

When I remove the line *logFolderContent.reverse()*, the script prints all the file name (meaning they're meeting the requirement below) and crashes when it reaches filenames with today's date.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I reverse the group logFolderContent"
are there really  584 files in the folder ? are 15 of them without .txt ?

Comment: @pwnsauce  .  list.reverse()  .  Instead of [file1, file2, file3] it would be [file3, file2, file1]

Comment: @pwnsauce  I'll put the printed output under the code.  Maybe that will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a for-loop instead a while-loop, which would look like

```
for i, file in enumerate(logFolderContent):
    if file.startswith(today): # Assuming the files always start with the date
        eligibleLogs.append(i)
        # -1 gets last item in list | most recent
        print("eligibleLogs[i] = ", eligibleLogs[-1]) 
    elif not file.endswith(".txt"):
        print("Non-text file found and ignored")
        print(logFolderContent[i])
```

If it is possible for a non text file to also start with date then swap the if statements around so it checks first that the file is a text file. Or add an and statement so it startswith date and endswith .txt

A big problem with what you had was because of this line and a try / except statement

```
print("eligibleLogs[x] = ", eligibleLogs[x])
```

The problem is that because not every file matches the date, the size of `eligibleLogs` does not match `x` so it is almost guaranteed that you will only get one item max in your list the moment the while loop terminates.

For example, your first match might be file number 100, therefore your list has 1 item in it but you then try to get the item at index 100 which causes an IndexError. Your loop then terminates and you get the values you weren't expecting.

Additionally you are probalaly aware, but just pointing it out.

```
eligibleLogs.append(i)
```

Is appending the index of the file that it matches. Maybe you would prefer this so your list contains the filenames of matches found.

```
eligibleLogs.append(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Steven Summers (see his answer above) and a little time playing with my code, I have finally got the script working as desired.  If anyone else is trying to search a string for today's date in Python, I have rewritten my code to serve a more general purpose and put it below.  Thank you to everyone who helped and hopefully this code will be helpful for others.

```
import os
import datetime
# <><><><><><><><><><>  Get Today's Date  <><><><><><><><><><>
today = datetime.date.today()
today = str(today)
# <><><><><><><><><><>  Get Today's Files  <><><><><><><><><><>
folder = "folderlocation"
folderContent = os.listdir(folder)
eligibleFiles = []
for i, file in enumerate(folderContent):
     if file.startswith(today):  # or -> if today in file
          eligibleFiles.append(file)
print(eligibleFiles)
```